# Convert Text Total To display Currency

Tags: vb.net

Hi I'm new to VB and I need help with learning how to convert my text total to currency. Instead of add "$" in font can I do something else to get the right dollar amount Display. Example below is my code:

```
intCostPerKWat = Convert.ToInt32(TxtCostPerKWat.Text) * 1.5
intAppliancePerKWat = Convert.ToInt32(TxtAppliancePerKWat.Text)
intHourPerDay = Convert.ToInt32(TxtHoursPerDay.Text) * 1
intWaterPerHours = Convert.ToInt32(TxtWaterPerHours.Text) * 1
decCostPerGallon = Convert.ToDecimal(TxtCostPerGallon.Text) * 2

LblDaily.Text = "$" & intCostPerKWat + intAppliancePerKWat + intHourPerDay +      intWaterPerHours + decCostPerGallon
```

Comment: shouldnt you multiply `decCostPerGallon` rather than add?  `value.ToString("C2")` is probably what you are after

Comment: Hi Plutonix can you explain to me a bit more about multiply rather than add. What I'm trying to to do is ask the user for input at Cost Per KWat. Once user put in an input Cost Per KWat is multiply by 1.5. Then add to Appliance Per KWat and so forth to get my total daily usage. Am I doing something wrong? Can you help me to get it right thank you.

Comment: If you are about to create a currency converter. Look at this [Topic](http://www.sourcecodester.com/visual-basic/currency-converter.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FormatCurrency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3352e6f5(v=vs.90).aspx) method to accomplish this.

```
dim Total as decimal = intCostPerKWat + intAppliancePerKWat + intHourPerDay +      intWaterPerHours + decCostPerGallon
LblDaily.Text = FormatCurrency(Total, , , TriState.True, TriState.True)
```

Hope that helps,

Comment: Hi Eric, Thank you for the information. I'm a student that currently taking SW programming. Hope I can able to help other just like you couple years down the line. Once again thank you!!!

Comment: Glad I was able to help! if this was the correct answer you can also help me out, by marking it as the correct answer. it'll give me more points. Best of luck with your coding.

Comment: Hi Eric, I'm new to this site. How can I mark correct for you to earn the point?

Comment: I believe there should be a check mark to the left of my answer.